LED as a power source
I'm totally noob at physics, and I need some data verification. A person said that they used an LED as a power source. Citation:

[...] it is possible to use an LED as a voltage / current source if you fire a laser into it. You have to choose the LED and Laser wavelengths carefully, but it's possible to get enough to power a microcontroller. [...]


It was a high-efficacy 460 nm blue LED [...] The laser was a very cheap "purple" laser-pointer with a stated wavelength of 405 nm.
With those, I was able to generate 2.5 V with no load attached to the LED. I was able to power [...] microcontroller and have it blink a green LED - so there was a decent amount of current available, I don't recall exactly how much. [...] the laser pointer was basically a 1 mW, class 1 laser such as you'd get on a keyring. [...]

So, my question is: how to choose parameters of the laser and the LED to get the best performance (and durability)?

Many fundamental laws of physics are reversible. If you turn a motor, it generates electrical power, if you apply electrical power to a generator, it turns like a motor. Since applying a voltage to an LED produces light, the reverse process should be possible: exposing it to light can produce a voltage. However, no processes are exactly reversible because of effects like friction, which lead to irreversible dissipation of energy. For efficiency, motors and generators are designed differently and LEDs and photodiodes are designed differently, but they work on the same physical principles.

Yes, one can use LEDs as photodiodes. The efficiency is pretty poor, though. If you want to build a practical photoelectric power coupler, use either a photodiode or a solar cell.
If you wanted to get serious about efficiency then you would have to select components that have high conversion efficiencies and that have the proper spectral characteristics. There are multiple loss mechanisms at work here. First there is the efficiency of the laser (or other light source). How much of the electrical power is being converted to light and how much ends up as heat? Diode lasers can achieve 40-50% efficiency. The data sheets of common 808nm 200mW laser diodes (they are used as pump lasers for green lasers if I am not mistaken) promises 200mW output power for an electrical input of 260mA*1.7V=442mW i.e. an efficiency of 45%. Other manufacturers are giving 1.8V to 2.2V operating voltages for 500mW devices (at 500mA), which would result in slightly lower efficiencies, so I would think that 35-40% is, in practice, going to be as good as it gets on the emitter side with cheap devices.
Silicon solar cells have bandgaps of 1.12eV, which would equal a wavelength of roughly 1100nm, which is longer than the wavelength of these lasers, but not by much, so we can expect to convert on the order of 808nm/1100nm=0.73 or approx. 73% of the laser light into electrical energy at best. There is also the quantum efficiency loss, which will probably shave another 10% or more off total efficiency. So we can not hope to get more than 0.73*0.9=65% of conversion efficiency on the receiver side. There are thermodynamic and electrical losses in addition because the receiver is working at room temperature or above and the electrical current causes ohmic losses in the semiconductor's metallization and wires, so in practice even 50% would probably be considered a good result. My best guess is that it's even less than that, but I never tried to do actual measurements with calibrated optical power sources/ power meters.
Putting transmitter and receiver side losses together might get us to 0.35*0.65=22% overall efficiency. I would suspect that optical losses will probably reduce that by a considerable amount in addition. I have never done any optimization on these setups, but bolting a cheap laser diode and a cheap solar cell module together got us in one experiment to an efficiency of a few percent (i.e. we were probably losing close to 80% or more of the light due to coupling). Since we only needed a few mW of electrical power in this case that was perfectly fine. We got what we needed and then some. If you do everything right you might get 50-100mW of power output from 1-1.2W electrical input into a 500mW laser diode. It's certainly worth trying if you have the need for absolutely clean isolated electrical power. I believe to have seen commercial devices of this kind that are being used on high voltage power lines to power diagnostic circuits through glass fiber links, but I don't know how efficient those devices are. I can't remember the manufacturer either.
